# How to acess the following property in this Json - JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have the following code that get the JSON in this URl :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyCg3WitBUQl5ifC2QygQaZUPOSRMKfSD5E&channelId=UCPSDAF3Htm3AIxw4OUM3Lew&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
```

I can acess the propierty "nextPageToken" and get your value with the following code:

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyCg3WitBUQl5ifC2QygQaZUPOSRMKfSD5E&pageToken="
                        + nextPageToken + "&channelId=" + new GetListAndPLayListYoutube().getIdUsuario()
                        + "&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50");

        System.out.println(json.get("nextPageToken"));
```

But i try Acess the property inside of "items" what is "videoId" and get the value of videoId, but not work, how can get the value of videoId

Comment: Jose, What's your exact problem? You parse  "nextPageToken" from your response and append it with your URL for loading Next Page.

Comment: my exact problem is how to acess the value of videoId in this json, yes i append the nextPageToken for loading Next Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to get `videoid` from `json` String.

pass your `json` string object from `parseJson()` method:

```
 private void parseJson(String responseString){
        try {

            Object object = new JSONTokener(responseString).nextValue();
            if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    Object object1  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (object1 instanceof JSONObject) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) object1;
                        JSONObject jsonObject2= jsonObject1.optJSONObject("id");
                        String videoId = jsonObject2.optString("videoId");
                        System.out.println("videoId=" + videoId);
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Its work ! I know little about JSON, I'll study more about JSON

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you querying Youtube's `Search API` and extracting results from response. In which case, I would recommend using Google's API Client library ([**here**](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/)) for `Java` instead of writing your own implementation.

[**Here**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java) are some examples of how to search Youtube using Google's API client and retrieve video information.